# OpenSSL bad hostname lookup Windows C

Tags: c, windows, openssl

I am trying to get the SSL/TLS client with OpenSSL from here: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client to build and run in visual studio.

I have it successfully building in visual studio, but it won't run successfully.
Currently it will run to `res = BIO_do_connect(web);` and`ssl_err = ERR_get_error();` eventually failing at the following `if (!(1 == res))` the console output is `bad hostname lookup`
I've looked around to try and find some solution, but nothing seems effective.

The H file I'm using is pretty much the same as the one at the openssl.org. with the exception of the addition of

```
typedef struct {
    int status_code;
    char *reason;
    char *content;
}   HttpResponse;
```

This is pretty much my first run in C, I've done Java before, so if someone has any insight, that would be great. Or if they can point to an example of an https post request for Windows in C.

```
#include "openssl-bio-fetch.h"
#include "corecrt_wstdio.h"

#ifndef HEADER_X509_H
#include <openssl/x509.h>
/* openssl/x509.h ends up #include-ing this file at about the only
* appropriate moment. */
#endif

int verify_callback(int preverify, X509_STORE_CTX* x509_ctx);

void init_openssl_library(void);
void print_cn_name(const char* label, X509_NAME* const name);
void print_san_name(const char* label, X509* const cert);
void print_error_string(unsigned long err, const char* const label);


const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!SRP:!PSK:!CAMELLIA:!RC4:!MD5:!DSS";

#if 0
const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = "kEECDH:kEDH:kRSA:AESGCM:AES256:AES128:3DES:SHA256:SHA84:SHA1:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP:!LOW:!MEDIUM!ADH:!AECDH";
#endif

#if 0
const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = NULL;
#endif

#if 0
const char* PREFERRED_CIPHERS =

/* TLS 1.2 only */
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
"ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
"ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"

/* TLS 1.2 only */
"DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
"DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:"
"DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"
"DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:"

/* TLS 1.0 only */
"DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:"
"DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:"
"DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:"
"DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:"

/* SSL 3.0 and TLS 1.0 */
"EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:"
"EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:"
"DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:"
"DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA";
#endif


void add_char_header(char *current, char *key, char *value)
{
    strcat(current, "\r\n");
    strcat(current, key);
    strcat(current, ": ");
    strcat(current, value);
}

void add_int_header(char *current, char *key, int value)
{
    char *buffer = malloc(5);
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", value);
    strcat(current, "\r\n");
    strcat(current, key);
    strcat(current, ": ");
    strcat(current, buffer);
    free(buffer);
}

void parse_http_response(char *resp, HttpResponse *response)
{
  response.reason = "";
  response.content = "";
}

char * buildRequest(char *request) {

    size_t size;
    size = strlen("{\"client_ip\":\"10.20.30.40\"}");
    strcpy(request, "{\"client_ip\":\"10.20.30.40\"}");
    printf("pks-368\n");
    return request;
}

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    char *request = malloc(225);
    buildRequest(request);

    HttpResponse response;
    response.reason = calloc(1, 64);
    response.content = calloc(1, 10 * 1024);
    response.status_code = 0;
    int a = openssl_fetch(request, &response);
    fprintf(stderr, "C %d", response.status_code);
    fprintf(stderr, "A %s", response.content);
    fprintf(stderr, "B %s", response.reason);
    printf("Paused");
}

int openssl_fetch(char *request, HttpResponse *response)
{
    char *HOST_NAME = "google.com";
    char *HOST_PORT = "443";

    char *hostname = calloc(1, 100);
    strcpy(hostname, HOST_NAME);
    strcat(hostname, ":");
    strcat(hostname, HOST_PORT);

    long res = 1;
    int ret = 1;
    unsigned long ssl_err = 0;

    SSL_CTX* ctx = NULL;
    BIO *web = NULL, *out = NULL;
    SSL *ssl = NULL;

    do {
        init_openssl_library();

        const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(NULL != method))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "SSLv23_method");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(ctx != NULL))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "SSL_CTX_new");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_callback);

        SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 5);
        const long flags = SSL_OP_ALL | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
        long old_opts = SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
        UNUSED(old_opts);

        const char *file_loc = "C:\\Users\\$USER\\Desktop\\trusted-roots.pem";

        res = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, file_loc, NULL);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(1 == res))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations -- [%s]\n", ssl_err);
        }

        web = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(web != NULL))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "BIO_new_ssl_connect");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        res = BIO_set_conn_hostname(web, hostname);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(1 == res))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "BIO_set_conn_hostname");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        BIO_get_ssl(web, &ssl);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(ssl != NULL))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "BIO_get_ssl");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        res = SSL_set_cipher_list(ssl, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(1 == res))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "SSL_set_cipher_list");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        res = SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, HOST_NAME);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(1 == res))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "SSL_set_tlsext_host_name");
        }

        out = BIO_new_fp(stdout, BIO_NOCLOSE);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(NULL != out))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "BIO_new_fp");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        res = BIO_do_connect(web);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(1 == res))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "BIO_do_connect");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        res = BIO_do_handshake(web);
        ssl_err = ERR_get_error();

        if (!(1 == res))
        {
            print_error_string(ssl_err, "BIO_do_handshake");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        X509* cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
        if (cert) { X509_free(cert); } /* Free immediately */

        if (NULL == cert)
        {
            print_error_string(X509_V_ERR_APPLICATION_VERIFICATION, "SSL_get_peer_certificate");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);

        if (!(X509_V_OK == res))
        {
            print_error_string((unsigned long)res, "SSL_get_verify_results");
            break; /* failed */
        }

        char message[2048];
        strcpy(message, "POST ");
        strcat(message, HOST_RESOURCE);
        strcat(message, " HTTP/1.1 ");
        add_char_header(message, "Host", HOST_NAME);
        add_char_header(message, "Connection", "close");
        add_char_header(message, "Accept", "*/*");
        add_int_header(message, "Content-Length", (int)strlen(request));
        strcat(message, "\r\n\r\n");
        strcat(message, request);

        BIO_puts(web, message);

        char buff[6144] = { 0 };
        int len = 0;
        do {

            len = BIO_read(web, buff, sizeof(buff));
        } while (len > 0 || BIO_should_retry(web));

        ret = 0;

        parse_http_response(buff, response);
        free(hostname);
    } while (0);

    if (out)
        BIO_free(out);

    if (web != NULL)
        BIO_free_all(web);

    if (NULL != ctx)
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return ret;
}

void init_openssl_library(void)
{
    (void)SSL_library_init();

    SSL_load_error_strings();
#if defined (OPENSSL_THREADS)
    //    fprintf(stdout, "Warning: thread locking is not implemented\n");
#endif
}

void print_cn_name(const char* label, X509_NAME* const name)
{
    int idx = -1, success = 0;
    unsigned char *utf8 = NULL;

    do
    {
        if (!name) break; /* failed */

        idx = X509_NAME_get_index_by_NID(name, NID_commonName, -1);
        if (!(idx > -1))  break; /* failed */

        X509_NAME_ENTRY* entry = X509_NAME_get_entry(name, idx);
        if (!entry) break; /* failed */

        ASN1_STRING* data = X509_NAME_ENTRY_get_data(entry);
        if (!data) break; /* failed */

        int length = ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&utf8, data);
        if (!utf8 || !(length > 0))  break; /* failed */

        fprintf(stdout, "  %s: %s\n", label, utf8);
        success = 1;

    } while (0);

    if (utf8)
        OPENSSL_free(utf8);

    if (!success)
        fprintf(stdout, "  %s: <not available>\n", label);
}

void print_san_name(const char* label, X509* const cert)
{
    int success = 0;
    GENERAL_NAMES* names = NULL;
    unsigned char* utf8 = NULL;

    do
    {
        if (!cert) break; /* failed */

        names = X509_get_ext_d2i(cert, NID_subject_alt_name, 0, 0);
        if (!names) break;

        int i = 0, count = sk_GENERAL_NAME_num(names);
        if (!count) break; /* failed */

        for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
        {
            GENERAL_NAME* entry = sk_GENERAL_NAME_value(names, i);
            if (!entry) continue;

            if (GEN_DNS == entry->type)
            {
                int len1 = 0, len2 = -1;

                len1 = ASN1_STRING_to_UTF8(&utf8, entry->d.dNSName);
                if (utf8) {
                    len2 = (int)strlen((const char*)utf8);
                }

                if (len1 != len2) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "  Strlen and ASN1_STRING size do not match (embedded null?): %d vs %d\n", len2, len1);
                }

                if (utf8 && len1 && len2 && (len1 == len2)) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "  %s: %s\n", label, utf8);
                    success = 1;
                }

                if (utf8) {
                    OPENSSL_free(utf8), utf8 = NULL;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "  Unknown GENERAL_NAME type: %d\n", entry->type);
            }
        }

    } while (0);

    if (names)
        GENERAL_NAMES_free(names);

    if (utf8)
        OPENSSL_free(utf8);

    if (!success)
        fprintf(stdout, "  %s: <not available>\n", label);

}

int verify_callback(int preverify, X509_STORE_CTX* x509_ctx)
{
    int depth = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth(x509_ctx);
    int err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(x509_ctx);

    if (depth == 0) {
    }

    if (preverify == 0)
    {
        if (err == X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY\n");
        else if (err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED\n");
        else if (err == X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN\n");
        else if (err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_NOT_YET_VALID)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_NOT_YET_VALID\n");
        else if (err == X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_ERR_CERT_HAS_EXPIRED\n");
        else if (err == X509_V_OK)
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = X509_V_OK\n");
        else
            fprintf(stdout, "  Error = %d\n", err);
    }

#if !defined(NDEBUG)
    return 1;
#else
    return preverify;
#endif
}

void print_error_string(unsigned long err, const char* const label)
{
    const char* const str = ERR_reason_error_string(err);
    if (str)
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", str);
    else
        fprintf(stderr, "%s failed: %lu (0x%lx)\n", label, err, err);
}
```

Comment: You should probably reduce the program a little bit more. There's a fair amount of extra cruft and I can't tell if its being used or not. Does the problem occur with the unmodified version of the wiki sample program? What is the string for `hostname` when `res = BIO_set_conn_hostname(web, hostname);` executes?

Comment: Okay, I reduced the program a bit, let me know if I should pare it down to a greater extent.

Comment: `hostname` is `google.com:443` at that point during execution.

Comment: Oh, in regards to the unmodified version, if I just set up the c and h file, it won't compile. Things that I have to adjust are: commenting the `InstallDebugTrapHandler` and using `# define ASSERT(x) UNUSED(X)` then it compiles.

Comment: Since the unmodified version works, then you should probably start backing out your changes until you find the offending block of code.

Comment: So to clarify, it will compile, but it also dies at the same spot.

Comment: @jww any thoughts? If both the unmodified version doesn't work either?